# How to get all the data from a specific room with socket.io after disconnected

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I have some issues with writeble streams. Instead to write another line, the stream delete the old lines and recreate the file...

The second problem I have is that I don't know how to get the user when is disconnecting..

In this server I built a small chat app that will log everything into a txt file. I need to detect when the user disconnected, and send the file by email.

```
This gets the socket name created by the user, and the  
const writeToDocument = async (socketID, data) => {
    const pathFile = path.join(__dirname, 'data', socketID + '.txt');
    const file = fs.createWriteStream(pathFile, {
        flags: 'w'
    });
    file.write(data);
};
```

I am trying to:

1. instead to write the file with the user input, the file should have the key, not the value (need this to be unique file name)
2. get each user when it gets disconnected and the room that he was in. I need this because after the room is empty, I will send the file to each emails and delete the chat file

```
io.on('connection', socket => {

    socket.on('join_room', async data => {
        socket.join(data); 
        writeToDocument(data, 'New user entered in the chat... \n \n');
    });

    socket.on('send_message', data => {
        socket.to(data.room).emit('receive_message', data);
        console.log(data);
        writeToDocument(data.room, `New message: [${data.time}] --> ${data.author} ${data.email}: ${data.message}`);
    });

    socket.on('disconnecting', () => {
        
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        
    });
});
```